# Connected sum of two non homeomorphic surfaces

Tags: general-topology, surfaces, projective-space

I must solve this exercise:

> $S_1, S_2, S_3, S_4$ are four pairwise non-homeomorphic surfaces which
>   are connected and compact. 
>   Is it correct that $S_1\#S_2$ is not homeomorphic to $S_3\#S_4$ ?

I tried to find a counterexample in order to prove that it is not correct. 
My approach is the following:

- I choose a surface $S_1$
- Classification theorem says that $S_1$ is homeomorphic to a sphere or to a connected sum of tori or to a connected sum of projective planes.
- I decide $S_1$ to be homeomorphic to a sum of three projective planes: $S_1 \cong \mathbb{P} \# \mathbb{P} \#\mathbb{P}$
- I take $S_2$ = sphere, $S_3$ = torus T, $S_4$ = projective plane $\mathbb{P}$
- I have four pairwise non homeomorphic functions, but $S_1 \# S_2 =S_1$ and $T\#\mathbb{P} \cong \mathbb{P} \#\mathbb{P} \#\mathbb{P}$ so $S_1 \# S_2 \cong T\#\mathbb{P}$

In this way I found a counterexamle which proved that there exists a case in which $S_1, S_2, S_3, S_4$ are four pairwise non-homeomorphic surfaces but $S_1 \# S_2 \cong T\#\mathbb{P}$ ($A \implies \neg B$). So the question in the exercise is false.

Is my answer right?

Comment: But you make a specific choice for you surfaces. So this proof isn't general at all.

Comment: I thought about this as a counterexample which should prove that $\neg B \implies A \rightarrow\leftarrow $

Comment: I don't see how this is a counterexample. You have proven that $S_1\#S_2$ is homeomorphic to $S_3\#S_4$. Or am i misunderstanding your initial statement?

Comment: I think I found a case in which $S_1, S_2, S_3, S_4$ are non homeomorphic but $S_1 \# S_2$ is homeomorphic to $S_3 \# S4$, so "$S_1, S_2, S_3, S_4$ non homeomorphic" $\nRightarrow S_1 \# S_2 \cong S_3 \# S4$

Comment: But you found a case in which the implication seems to be valid. To use contraposition, as you wanted, you should find a case in which $S_1\#S_2 \not\cong S_3\#S_4\implies S_1, S_2, S_3, S_4$ not mutually non-homeomorphic.

Comment: I tried to formulate the problem in a clearer way

Comment: Now you have proven that generally the statement is false, as you said. (My apologies if i was a bit of a nuisance)

Comment: @NDewolf no, on the contrary you helped me a lot. Thank you!